# How to add CSS style to focused anchor in HTML

Tags: html, css, anchor

On page 1 there is a link which takes you to a certain point on page 2

`<a href="page2.html#position">MY TEXT HERE</a>`

This takes you straight to the anchor (position) on page 2 with the following code

```
<a name="position"> MORE TEXT HERE</a>
```

Now, my question is how can I change the text and background color when #position is in the URL?

For example: www.domainname.com/page2.html#position

This is the CSS I used but doesn't work:

```
#position {
color:#ff0000;
background-color:#f5f36e;
}
```

Here is a example http://jsfiddle.net/jvtcj/2/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `:target` selector:

```
a:target, /* or simply */
:target {
    /* CSS to style the focused/target element */
}
```

You'd be better off using the `id` of a particular element to receive the focus, since named-anchors seem to have been dropped, if not deprecated entirely.

References:

- [CSS selectors, level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

Comment: Thank you for your help this worked. I also had to add the class

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS3 `:target` peseudo selector: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/stay-on-target

Also, don't use the old myth `<a name="destination">...</a>`, all you need is to `id` the section you want to jump to, e.g. `<section id="destination">...</section>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#position2" id="position">MY TEXT HERE</a>
...
<a name="position2" id="pos2"> MORE TEXT HERE</a>
```

... in css:

```
a[name=position2]:target{     
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<a name="position" class="position"> MORE TEXT HERE</a>
```

And in CSS use

```
.position {
color:#ff0000;
background-color:#f5f36e;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jvtcj/4/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added the class and it worked, I also had to give the CSS a :target

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the  tag.

You can see how here using your example

http://jsfiddle.net/h5NZh/

```
<a id="position" href="#position">MY TEXT HERE</a>
```